# Split .btn-group onto another line, at certain screen sizes

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm playing around with **Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6)**, and I'm liking what I see so far. One issue I've come across, is how to make a `btn-group` with checkbox/radios in, that will move onto a 2nd line once it gets too wide for the page. So an example:

http://codepen.io/youradds/pen/KaBJEm

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        Piscine
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        Piscine
      </label>
.... loads of other buttons too
</div>
```

As per this documentation:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

If you scale the CodePen down in width, you will see what I mean. What I would like to happen, is for it to move onto a 2nd line (instead of forcing the page width to accommodate it).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `btn-group` like many other elements in Bootstrap 4, now use flexbox. There are also new [flexbox utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) to enable custom behavior.

In this case you can simply use `flex-wrap`...

```
<div class="btn-group flex-wrap" data-toggle="buttons">
    ...
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/8MYqS2EWGO

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm. Wish I'd known about that yesterday! Are there any good tutorials to get your head around the next flex stuff? I have to admit, I'm still a bit baffled by parts of it. For example, where does `p-1` come into the equation. BS have some stuff on the flex page, but it doesn't really explain those bits (to a flex novice)